# Facebook API batch request with Google Apps Script

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-apps-script

I'm struggling with building a batch request in Apps Script to change multiple Facebook ad set budgets in one API call.

Facebook gives me the following example (curl):

```
curl -F 'access_token=____' 
    -F 'batch=[
               {
                "method": "POST",
                "relative_url": "<API_VERSION>/6004251715639",
                "body": "redownload=1&bid_info={\"clicks\":100}"
               },
               {
                "method": "POST",
                "relative_url": <API_VERSION>/v6004251716039",
                "body": "redownload=1&bid_info={\"clicks\":100}"
               },
               {
                "method": "POST",
                "relative_url": "<API_VERSION>/6004251715839",
                "body": "redownload=1&bid_info={\"clicks\":100}"
               }
              ]' https://graph.facebook.com
```

My code in Apps Script is the following:

```
function testBatchRequest() {

  var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/?access_token=XXX",
        batch=[

               {
                "method": "POST",
                "relative_url": "/<AD SET ID>",
                "body": "redownload=1&daily_budget=25000"
               },
               {
                "method": "POST",
                "relative_url":"/<AD SET ID>",
                "body": "redownload=1&daily_budget=25000"
               }];

  url = url + "&batch=" + JSON.stringify(batch);
  Logger.log(url);

  var options = {
      "method": 'POST',
      "followRedirects" : true,
      "muteHttpExceptions": true
  };

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);


  var json = result.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);

  Logger.log(json);
  Logger.log(data); 
}
```

As a response I get "Invalid argument".

To asnwer the potential SDK question: I haven't found a working way to integrate the JavaScript SDK in App Script.

It's the first time for me working with batch requests and I still consider myself to be a beginner. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I believe that this can happen when you encode the entire string including the square brackets. Try `batch={......}` and just JSON.strinigy() that string.

Answer (score 0):

This took quite a bit of frustrating trial and error, as the request worked fine pasted in Postman, but the solution is that the batch variable needs to be URL-encoded on top of being Stringified.

So the above code will work if you instead do

```
 url = url + "&batch=" + encodeURIComponent( JSON.stringify(batch) );
```